# SvelteJS: Dynamically add N components, where N is the integer value of an input element

Tags: svelte

Using SvelteJS v2.16.1.
Trying to dynamically add N componenets where N is the value entered in an input element.
Here is how it, roughly, looks now:

```
<input min="1" type="number" bind:value="quantity"/>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      quantity: 1
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I would like to use {quantity} in perhaps something like {#each} to dynamically create new  elements.
Sort of like this:

```
<input min="1" type="number" bind:value="quantity"/>
{#each quantity as i}
  <input type="text />
{/each}
```

But {quantity} is an integer value, so I cannot use it in {#each}.

Any suggestions on how o approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of an `each` block should be an array (or array-like object, i.e. it has a `length` property). So you can just do `Array(quantity)`, like so:

```html
<input min="1" type="number" bind:value="quantity"/>
{#each Array(quantity) as i}
  <input type="text">
{/each}
```

[REPL demo](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=2.16.1&gist=b4302eb5392808e850fe9c46af6f10bd).

Comment: Very nice. Thank you for your prompt reply.